# Can I avoid using global callback function when loading JSON-P?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I want to load my Google Calendar feed on my web page using JSON-P. To make the main content on the page load quicker, I inject the script tag for JSON-P into the head tag only after page is loaded. Google Calendar API returns a script with callback function, see example [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample).

Is it possible to avoid using global function as a callback function? I would like to wrap all the necessary code for injecting the tag and parsing the results inside one wrapper function.

Comment: Nope. That's how JSONP has to work. One callback function to "execute" the resulting data of the jsonp call.

Comment: No. The callback must be available from the global scope - yet it might be a namespaced function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you are using JSON-P calls, the server returns something like below:

```
callback({...})
```

After you use `<script>` element to reference this JSON-P call URL, browser will download the JavaScript code and execute it, which means to execute your `callback` function using server-provided data.

If you don't want callback function to pollute your global namespace, just add some namespace to your callback function, like `com.mycode.callback`.

The biggest advantage of using JSON-P is that it can work around [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in browser and you can easily use data from other domains.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is using a method of the global where you application lives.

```
MYAPP.method({...});
```