# Javascript angular function definition

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, angularjs-http

```
function callbackformeetup (data) {
  console.log(data);
}

app.service('MeetupSearch', function($http){
  this.search = function(zip, word){
    return $http.jsonp('https://api.meetup.com/find/groups?key=111111111111&sign=true&photo-host=public&zip=80202&upcoming_events=true&text=ruby&callback=callbackformeetup');
    };
});
```

So the above works. When I define the function above the app.service, the api call works and successfully returns me data. However, this does not work:

```
app.service('MeetupSearch', function($http){
   function callbackformeetup (data) {
     console.log(data);
   }

  this.search = function(zip, word){
    return $http.jsonp('https://api.meetup.com/find/groups?key=52147258472159b1938714519435029&sign=true&photo-host=public&zip=80202&upcoming_events=true&text=ruby&callback=callbackformeetup');
    };
});
```

What gives? Why does that not work when I define the function inside?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518637/can-i-avoid-using-global-callback-function-when-loading-json-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesnt work because `callbackformeetup` isn't available as a global function, and thats a condition to make `jsonp` work

Comment: Oh really? I didn't see that in the jsonp docs. Thanks!